# used to or past simple

Tags: past-tense, used-to

Which of the sentences below is correct?

1. My son used to play video games a lot when he was a child.
2. My son played video games a lot when he was a child.

Are they both correct? If not, is there a difference in their meaning?

Thanks!

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct.

The main difference between them is that the first one implies that the son doesn't play video games much any more; the second one leaves this question open.

[Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/used%20to) defines *used to* as:

> used to say something happened repeatedly in the past but does not happen now