# Used to shout / Shouted

Tags: meaning-in-context

### Which form works better in this text? He shouted VS He used to shout

1. Every time the Prophet saw him, **He shouted at him**: "What are you
   doing there?
2. Every time the Prophet saw him, **He used to shout at him**: "What
   are you doing there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [used to or past simple](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516925/used-to-or-past-simple)

Comment: 1. is fine. 2. is acceptable, but it would better recast as "Every time the Prophet saw him, he **would** shout at him: "What are you doing there?

Comment: @BillJ Or "When the Prophet saw him he used to shout at him 'What are you doing there?'"